# depth of channel showing in nsqadmin increasing fast when producer send message to same topic via different nsqd

Tags: nsq

I play with nsqd a little bit and met the prob mentioned in the title. But when I send message via single nsqd, there is no such prob. Does this mean message should always be sent via same nsqd?

Here is my project. https://github.com/hoozecn/nsqd-cluster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's resolved by set a higher MaxInFlight value.

ref: https://github.com/nsqio/nsq/issues/1213